# how to obtain the location of the variable as linker map file?

Tags: c, linker, client-server, memory-address

I want to place some variable at a specific address and later using this address on the master side (Masters contains an file consisting of the variables and addresses) to read a variable value  by selecting the particular variable. Could anyone give me some ideas regarding this ??

Comment: Your question is too vague. **Edit** your question and explain it further. (Do not use comments for that purpose)

Comment: someone has commented it, So I replied for him. now he deleted that comment.

Answer (score 0):

To place a variable at a specific memory location, you need to declare the variable as being mapped to a specific **data section**. The syntax for this depends on the toolchain. After this, you can specify in the linker file where the data section should go.

In case You have more complex system and want to make sure the variable is located at the same address in each one of them you simply have to make you you map the data section containing the variable at the same virtual address and the MMU will take care of the rest.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hoe to do the mapping for RAM ?? Could you give some more information ??

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I am using visual studion C++ ide.

Comment: for MSVS I think you need to use #pragma data_seg("<DATA_SEG_NAME>") before the variable declaration.

Comment: for example: int a[10]; how to do this ?? I am new in programming. Could you help me ??

Comment: first of all, is this what you are trying to achieve? map a variable at a certain memory location